# How to get Firebase realtime database list items based on date

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get list of data from firebase realtime database in a Flutter project and apply a where condition to it.
database structure
[image: structure of the data]

and I would like to filter the list based on the date shown in the image.
I am using flutter_database package.

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("activities/${widget.project.id}");
```

I wonder how to apply the "where" condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use date field in the `orderByChild` and set the date in `startAt`

```
ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("activities").child('${widget.project.id}')
                      .orderByChild('date').startAt("2022-10-16 00:00:00.000");
print("------------------");
ref.once().then((value)  {
  print(value.snapshot.value);
  print("");
});
```